# Hungry for pistachios

Tags: situation, real

You are locked in a completely empty room with no tools. You are given a bag with cooked pistachios. Most of the pistachios are fully open, but some are only partially open. You are not able to open the latter pistachios with your hands, feet or teeth. Is there a way you can open them?

This is a real-world puzzle without any tricks.

P.S. I love pistachios. In fact I am going to have some right now!

Comment: Lol 3 answers in 3 minutes. And we all had the same idea!

Comment: The real question here is what kind of person locks themself in a room with only a bag of pistachios...

Comment: @HTM I agree. Only a total _nut_ would do that.

Comment: @HTM And why is he not trying to get out, instead of eating partially open pistachios...

Comment: I’m not really sure this counts as a puzzle. Having said that, I’m now going to eat some pistachios.

Comment: "the later pistachios" Should be "latter", not "later".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could

> try to pry open the pistachios with the shells of the ones that have already opened?

Comment: Seems that would require hands?

Comment: You got it! You can use hands you just don't have the strength to open then with your bare hands.

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps you could simply:

> Sit on them and crush the partially opened pistachios with your buttocks over and over until they open, using the natural pressure produced by the weight of your body. No hands, feet, or teeth required!

Another similar idea:

> You could push the pistachios, using your elbows, knees, bottom, nose, ears, forehead, etc., to slide them against the wall and once more use your body to crush them.

Also also:

> Just do some real painful WWE-style body slams on the pistachios on either the floor or wall!

Comment: *(hands over pistachios)* "Anyone want some?" - "No thanks, we're good"

Comment: +1 for WWE option

Comment: @Adib "The match looks almost over and..." "BY GOD! IT'S EL PISTACHIO WITH A STEEL CHAIR!"

Answer (score 7):

I'd try to

> use one half of a shell of an open one as a splitting wedge / lever to open one which is partially open. There should be a hole if it's partially open as you claim.

Another option would be to

> take two partially open pistachios, put the openings together and use *both* of them as a lever to open the other one, by twisting them. The weaker one should crack soon enough.

Answer (score 6):

smash the pistachio on the wall with your head until either one breaks.

Comment: I think your head will break first! 

Answer (score 6):

Swallow pistachios that have a closed shell so that so your stomach acid will melt the shells off.

Answer (score 2):

> Well, if time isn't a factor, you could always just grab some with your mouth and suck on them until your saliva digests and softens the shells sufficiently for you to open them with your tongue. I don't know how long that would take, but I assume it could probably happen eventually.

Answer (score 2):

You could...

> put them in your mouth for very long time so that they start to swell and after that, you can open them easily.